# Кодирование строки c помощью ключа?

Tags: php, шифрование

Мне нужно закодировать число 1358527277,
длинна будет не измена подскажите с помощью какой функции это можно реализовывать

Comment: @good, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Вообще нихрена не понятно.

Comment: (((((((((((((((

Comment: Шифрование _одного числа_ не имеет смысла. Имеет смысл лишь шифрование _произвольного_ текста/набора чисел. Для одного числа можно написать, например:

    encrypt() { return 1111111111; }
    decrypt() { return 1358527277; }

Comment: @VladD - если стоит задача, то смысл есть. @good, используй любой [Поточный шифр][1]


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80

Comment: @vv2cc: а чем тогда мой код не решение?

Comment: )))))))))))))

Comment: число не одно их много просто для примера взял это в качестве представления их длины

Answer (score 1):

Может полином CRC2 подойдет http://php.net/manual/ru/function.crc32.php или password_hash http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 0):

[mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mcrypt.php) двухстороннее шифрование различными способами, с помощью ключа. Доступен на множестве хостах